# How to set app theme data in different pages in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a list view on my homepage where if I clicked on it will move to a new page the first one the theme should be blue, and the next one the theme data should be red. 
Like how Chat Customization in Facebook's Messenger works.

Comment: Wrap your page into a Theme instance with the desired properties

Comment: so I will create an object class for Theme?

Comment: oh I saw it in the documentation thanks btw [link](https://flutter.io/cookbook/design/themes/)

Answer (score 9):

You should wrap your Page widget inside a Theme widget. Something like below:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Theme(
    data: ThemeData(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
    ),
    child: Builder(
      builder: (context) {
        return YourPageWidget(context);
      }
    ),
  );
}
```

There is one thing you should aware of. Using a `Builder()` to pass the latest `context` (including your custom theme data in this new context) to the child widget.

If not using Builder, in some cases, YourPageWidget can't get correct theme data with command `Theme.of(context)...`

For more information, you can reference the document [Create unique ThemeData](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/themes#creating-unique-themedata)